# Error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, debugging, error-handling

Thanks for taking your time to see this, I have tried everything I know until now and I continue getting the same error on lines 7, 10, 13 and 16 of the main (class Test)

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int res;

        res = new Calculadora.doAdd();
        System.out.println("The addition is: "+ res);

        res = new Calculadora.doMul ();
        System.out.println("\n The multiplication is: "+ res);

        res = new Calculadora.doDiv ();
        System.out.println("\n The division is:  "+ res);

        res = new Calculadora.doSub ();
        System.out.println("The substraction is: "+ res);

        Calculadora obj1 = new Calculadora ();
        Calculadora obj2 = new Calculadora ();
        Calculadora.contar();
        Calculadora.contar();
        System.out.println("Obj1: "+obj1.cont + " \nObj2: "+ obj2.cont);
    }
}//fin del main
```

Second program:

```
public class Calculadora
{
    public Addition add;
    public Substraction sub;
    public Multiplication mul;
    public Division div;

    static int cont = 0;

    static void contar()
    {
        cont++;
    }

    public Calculadora ()
    {
        add = new Addition();
        sub = new Substraction();
        mul = new Multiplication();
        div = new Division();
    }

    public int doAdd ()
    {
        return add.doAdd ();
    }

    public int doSub ()
    {
        return sub.doSub ();
    }

    public int doMul ()
    {
        return mul.doMul ();
    }

    public int doDiv ()
    {
        return div.doDiv ();
    }
}
```

The program of operation which has the attributes for the opperations:

```
public class Opperation 
{
    public int a, b;

    public Opperation ()
    {
        a = 1;
        b = 2;
    }
}
```

Finally, the operations which are rather easy.

```
public class Substraction extends Opperation //Substraction
{
    public int doSub ()
    {
        return a-b;
    }
}//substraction

public class Multiplication extends Opperation //Multiplication
{   
    public int doMul ()
    {
        return a*b;
    }
}//Multiplication

public class Division extends Opperation //Division
{
    public int doDiv ()
    {
        return a/b;
    }
}//Division

public class Addition extends Opperation//Addition
{
    public int doAdd ()
    {
        return a+b;
    }
}//Addition
```

I know there is an easier way to do a calculator, but the teacher asked it with the seven classes and I continue getting the same error pointing to the dot in the new

Comment: Could you please add more details on the error? If I had to take a stab in the dark here, I'd say it's an issue with importing your classes, but there's a good chance it's something else.

Comment: Sure the problem im getting is the next:    Test.java:7: error: cannot find symbol res=new Calculadora.doAdd();  
 symbol: class doAdd  
location: class Calculadora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are instantiating `Calculadora` is wrong

```
res = new Calculadora.doAdd();  // wrong.
```

should be change to

```
res = new Calculadora().doAdd();  //correct
```

or

```
Calculadora cal = new Calculadora();
res = cal.doAdd();
```